# WPF Icon and Uri

Tags: wpf, vb.net, resources, icons

I am trying to load an icon that is in my project directly in the main directory.
In order to do that i do this:

```
Dim uriSrc As Uri = New Uri("pack://ELE100WalkerWPF:,,,/assemblyName;Component/ShowMCF.png")
Dim bitmapImage As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage With {.UriSource = uriSrc}
Dim image As System.Windows.Controls.Image = New System.Windows.Controls.Image() With {.Source = bitmapImage}
```

This simply doesn't work even if for my styles i reference them in the same way:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ELE100WalkerWPF;component/Resources/Colors.xaml" />
```

The only difference is that my styles are defined in the MergeDictionary in the application.xaml like this

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Colors.xaml" />
```

Can somebody please explain why the image is not showing and how i can solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pack://ELE100WalkerWPF:...` is not a valid [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

You can also not set a BitmapImage's `UriSource` property without calling `BeginInit` and `EndInit`. Use the BitmapImage constructor that takes an Uri argument.

Provided that `ShowMCF.png` is located in the top level folder of your Visual Studio Project, and its  Build Action is set to `Resource`, this should work:

```
Dim uri As Uri = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/ShowMCF.png")
Dim bitmapImage As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage(uri)
```

If the image resource is in a referenced assembly (called ELE100WalkerWPF), you must included the assembly name like this:

```
Dim uri As Uri = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/ELE100WalkerWPF;component/ShowMCF.png")
Dim bitmapImage As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage(uri)
```

Comment: you nailed it Clemens !!

Comment: Ok It worked thanks to the initialization of the BitmapImage, but to make it work i had to set the URI like this: pack://application:,,,/ELE100WalkerWPF;component/ShowMCF.png :)

Comment: @StefanoAquila That indicates the image resource is in a different assembly, which you aren't mentioning in your question. If it's in the same assembly, you can omit the `ELE100WalkerWPF;component` part.

Comment: Neither do I. Could the problem of the URI be because i have an external app that includes my project?

Comment: That is a different assembly.